# AWS SDK in Perl

Tags: web-services, perl, sdk, amazon-web-services, transcoding

Whether it is possible to create AWS SDK in Perl?. I need to use AWS transcoder service from my perl script. But I wonder AWS SDK is not available for Perl(http://aws.amazon.com/code). Or do they have any other method to use PHP SDK in a Perl script?

Answer (score 4):

The API is just "sending specific things over HTTP". You don't need a language specific library for that, although it does make things easier. Anyone can write such a wrapper, and [some people already have done that for Perl](https://metacpan.org/search?q=aws).

Comment: Hi Quentin, Thanks for reply!!! Actually I want to use AWS transcoder service. Currently I have PHP script for the same and it uses autoload.php which is automatically created when on the installation of PHP SDK.

Comment: Which [has API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/api-reference.html) showing that HTTP requests you need to make.

Comment: This is fine Quentin, But i am getting input video file inforamtion through AWS SQS service. which uses Aws/Sqs/SqsClient library in PHP script. Can i use this same library on perl script too. or do we have any other method?

Comment: SQS also has [API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and there [are Perl wrappers](https://metacpan.org/search?q=SQS) for it. There are [ways to use PHP code from Perl](https://metacpan.org/search?q=php) but I haven't felt the need to try any of them.

Answer (score 3):

Years later, there is now [Paws](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws), a Perl AWS interface. It's on CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to write your own Perl modules to work with the AWS API. As remarked above, if you can make HTTP calls and create an HMAC signature, any language can do it.

However, there are already a lot of Perl modules on CPAN that address specific AWS functions, such as S3 or EC2. Go to http://www.cpan.org/src/ to search for what you need (e.g., SNS). You'll generally find something that will meet your need.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.timkay.com/aws/

I have found Tim Kay's "aws" and "s3" tools quite useful.  They are written in Perl.
It has the added advantage of --exec, so you can append commands directly to the output, in their original state from AWS.  It has been a terror for me to have international characters and other junk floating about as sad excuse for file names.  With Tim's toolset, I was able to workaround the problem by using the --exec to call for the prefix of the filename (also unique) and then act upon it directly, instead of mucking about with metacharacters and other nonsense.

For example:

```
/123/456/789/You can't be serious that this is really a filename.txt
/123/456/901/Oh!Yes I can! *LOL* Honest!.txt
```

To nuke the first one:

```
aws ls  --no-vhost mybucketname/123/456/789/  --exec='system "aws", "rm", "--no-vhost", "$bucket/$key"'
```

Simply put, the tool performs an equivalent "ls" on the S3 bucket, for that prefix, and returns ALL file names in that prefix, which are passed into the exec function.  From there, you can see I am blindly deleting whatever files are held within.

(note: --no-vhost helps resolve bucketnames with periods in them and you don't need to use long URLs to get from point a to point b.)